# How can I disable gnome-panel's context menu?

Tags: gnome

I'm using Ubuntu Precise(12.04) without Unity.

```
sudo apt-get -y install gnome-panel
```

logout and login selected [GNOME Classic]. Effect is on.

So, can I disable gnome-panel's context menu ?
It is appear Super-Alt-Right Click to top-panel or bottom-panel.
I want fixing my customized menu Icons.

Thanks.

Comment: how does disabling the context menu fix your customized menu icons?

Comment: Super-Alt-Right Clicking gnome-panel, make doesn't appear context menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually by using `~/.gconf/apps/panel/`. Run this command:

```
mkdir ~/gnomepanelbackup ; mv ~/.gconf/apps/panel ~/gnomepanelbackup
```

Then run:

```
killall gnome-panel
```

After running these commands you will have backup of gnome-panel settings in `/gnomepanelbackup` in your home directory.

Comment: Thank you for response.
I'm tried your guide.
But, Super-Alt-Right Click gnome-panel then, Behavior 
doesn't changed.
I want disable context menu.
[add panel]
[property]
[delete this panel]
[new panel]
Make Those context menu doesn't appear.

Sorry my poor English.
Thanks.